# Transforming a csv to a list of co-occurrence pairs in Python

Tags: python

My data is a csv that looks like:

```
 1     abc
 1     def
 2     ghi
 3     jkl
 3     mno
 3     pqr
```

I want to transform it into a list of all pairs that co-occur with the same number in column 1. Like this:

```
 abc; def
 jkl; mno
 mno; pqr
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far that doesn't work?

Comment: No `jkl; pqr` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your input csv file is not really a csv. It's more a file that can be parsed using `str.split`. Well.

Now, I'll get the tokens and use `itertools.groupby` using first column as key to group items with same first column.

Once you have that, filter out the lists with one 1 item, and apply a combination on the rest.

Write as a proper csv file:

```
import csv, itertools

    with open("test.csv") as f:
        with open("output.csv","w",newline="") as f2:
        # with open("output.csv","wb") as f2:   # uncomment for python 2 (comment above!)

            cw = csv.writer(f2,delimiter=";")
            for l in itertools.groupby((l.split() for l in f),lambda x : x[0]):
                grouped = set(x[1] for x in l[1])  # set avoids duplicate rows
                if len(grouped)>1:
                    for c in itertools.combinations(grouped,2):
                        cw.writerow(c)
```

result (corrected, yours is not correct):

```
abc;def
jkl;mno
jkl;pqr
mno;pqr
```

Comment: Looks great, thanks! I get this however: TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function (Python 2.7)

Comment: sorry I added the correct line for python 2. csv module must be handled with caution and it depends on the version of python (unless you have the latest revisions of 2.x or 3.x)

Comment: Thank you so much! Now this: line 148, in <module>
    cw.writerow(c)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: no, I think you made an indentation error while copying my code. You have to stay within the inner `with` when writing or `f2` will be closed. I have tested my code and it works. c is c and cw is cw. No error here.

Comment: Yes, thanks! Fixed the indentation now. Works! What is an easy tweak to get rid of rows with the same word in both columns in the output csv?

Comment: you mean the 2 occurrences of `jkl` ? can be done but which right side will you keep? the last or the first? in that case the combination stuff is useless.

Comment: No, sorry. I mean, if using the code on other material, and there are duplicates resulting in rows like jkl;jkl.